# phpunit install error: Cannot use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub as Stub

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have problem when installing phpunit.

I have `dl phpunit-6.5.5.phar`, rename it `phpunit.phar` and create the `phpunit.cmd`.

My problem is when i type `phpunit --version`.

An error returned to me :

> Fatal error: Cannot use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub as Stub
>   because the name is already in use in
>   phar://C:/bin/phpunit-6.5.5.phar/phpunit-mockobjects/Builder/InvocationMocker.php
>   on line 16

Has anyone encountered this error before?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem when using PHPUnit with the Symfony framework.

My directory path was `SymfonyTest7/App/Bin`.

Because the PHPUnit file you want to run is in your bin folder I had to run the commands as follows (Both are entered into your terminal):

```
1. php phpunit --version 
2. php bin/phpunit --version
```

The first option is used if you cd into the `bin` folder.

The second option is used if you are in your `project_name` folder.

If this was confusing to read, I have explained this better on a comment at this link:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000792390-PHPUNIT-6-Error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with phpunit-6.5.6 and php-7.0.0 / php-7.0.27.

I solved this in two ways:

1. update to php-7.1.14 and stay on phpunit-6.5.6
2. downgrade to phpunit-5.7.27 and stay on php-7.0.0